# C++: Reading data from printer

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, driver

I'm trying to read the status and some other information from a printer, however I'm not getting any data returned from the printer. I can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong?

I'm using Qt creator where I have included the WinSpool library

As a side note: This is my first time trying to read data from a piece of hardware.

The msdn pages for the printer functions are:
[SetPrinterData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [GetPrinterData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [OpenPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Code**

```
BOOL status = false;
HANDLE hPrinter = NULL;

PRINTER_DEFAULTS defaults;
defaults.pDatatype = (LPTSTR)__TEXT("RAW");
defaults.pDevMode = 0;
defaults.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_READ;

status = OpenPrinter((LPTSTR)__TEXT("CN551A"),&hPrinter,&defaults);

if(status) {
    qDebug() << "Status: OPEN OK";
}

// pValueName found in registry 
LPTSTR pValueName = (LPTSTR)"PrinterData";
DWORD type = REG_BINARY;
BYTE pData[2];
pData[0] = 0;
pData[1] = 0;

status = SetPrinterData(&hPrinter,pValueName,type,pData,sizeof(pData));
if(status) {
    qDebug() << "Status: SET OK";
}

BYTE buffer[263];
LPDWORD pcbNeeded = 0;
LPDWORD pType = (LPDWORD)REG_BINARY;

status = GetPrinterData(&hPrinter, pValueName,pType,buffer,sizeof(buffer),
pcbNeeded);

if(status) {
    qDebug() << "Status: GET OK";
    qDebug() << "pType: " << pType;
    qDebug() << "pcbNeeded " << pcbNeeded;
    qDebug() << "buffer " << *buffer;

    /* Prints a bunch of numbers
    for(int i =0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
        qDebug() << buffer[i];
    }
    */
}

ClosePrinter(&hPrinter);
```

**Output**

```
Status: OPEN OK 
Status: SET OK 
Status: GET OK 
pType:  0x3 
pcbNeeded  0x0 
buffer  1
```

I'm using Qt creator where I have included the WinSpool library

As a side note: This is my first time trying to acheive this.

**Edit**

[I found a C# program](http://www.primerahealthcare.com/support/slideprinter/DriverIntegrationStatusReaderandSourceCode.zip) which reads status and information in the `ReadBytesFromPrinter` function in `PrintLabel.cs` using Windows API calls, just like I would like to, but I still wasn't able to figure out my mistake/error. Thought I'd link it, if someone could spot what's wrong with my code compared to theirs.

Answer (score 0):

You're misinterpreting the return values of the `GetPrinterData` and `SetPrinterData`. Those calls are in fact failing, not succeeding. The return value for success is `ERROR_SUCCESS`, which I believe you'll find is zero. Any other value is the error code you need to display and investigate.  See the [MSDN entry for SetPrinterData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).